# Long running python process with Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, long-running-processes

I'm trying to run a python script in Google Cloud which will download 50GB of data once a day to a storage bucket. That download might take longer than the timeout limit on the Google Cloud Functions which is set to 9 minutes.
The request to invoke the python function is triggered by HTTP.

Is there a way around this problem ? I don't need to run a HTTP Restful service as this is called once a day from an external source. (Can't be scheduled) .

The whole premise is do download the big chuck of data directly to the cloud. 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

9 minutes is a hard limit for Cloud Functions that can't be exceeded.  If you can't split up your work into smaller units, one for each function invocation, consider using a different product.  Cloud Run limits to 15 minutes, and Compute Engine has no limit that would apply to you.

Answer (score -1):

[Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) may work well for that.

Here is a nice google blog [post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/how-to-schedule-a-recurring-python-script-on-gcp) that shows example of how to set up a python script.

p.s. you would probably want to connect it to the App Engine for the actual execution.